# Determine if specific string is in a 2d list

Tags: python, list

The list contains "C " and "C*" to start and changes to several other items as it progresses.

```
def hasWon(board):
    if "M " in board:
            return False
    elif "C " in board:
            return False
    elif "? " in board:
            return False
    elif "?*" in board:
            return False
    else:
            return True
```

If I run this it always returns true even when it should return false

Comment: Do you really want the spaces after the letters?  Do you mean to say, `if "M" in board` and so on?

Comment: I put it exactly as it would appear in the list

Comment: Can you add `print(board)` to `haswon()` just before `return True` and show us what it prints out? I'm pretty sure that `board` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: the full list is too long but this is a stub [['C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C '], ['C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C '], ['C ', 'C ', 'C*', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C*', 'C '], ['C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C '], ['C ', 'C ', 'C*', 'C*', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C '], ['C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C*', 'C*', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C '], ['C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C ', 'C '], ['C ', 'C ', 'C*', 'C*', 'C ', 'C ',

Comment: If `board` is the 2-d array, you need to loop over the elements. `in` doesn't recurse into the sub-arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `'C ' in board` you can use `any('C ' in row for row in board)`.

Comment: Thank You, this was very helpful.